# Neo4j embedded: filter on node properties using graph algorithm

Tags: properties, filter, neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I am using Neo4j embedded from eclipse and want to navigate through a network of trips and stations. They are connected the following way:

```
(t:Trip)-[:STOPS {arrival:"10:12:00", departure:"10:13:00"}]->(s:Station)
```

As a trip has several stops and there are several trips which stop at one station there are many connections. Sometimes it is not possible to get from one station to another without changing to a different trip. For that reason I use the following graph algo

```
    PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(PathExpanders.forType(RelTypes.STOPS), depth);
    ArrayList<Path> path = (ArrayList<Path>) finder.findAllPaths(source,target);
```

But I can't find if there are ways to filter on my properties `arrival` and `departure` because I want to find only trips which depart after a given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `PathExpanders.forType()` you need to use your custom implementation of [`PathExpander`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpander.html).

Your implementation would basically filter `path.endNode().getRelationships(RelTypes.STOPS)` for those having correct arrival and departure properties.